# Why am I getting this randint() error in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, random, attributeerror

My interpreter keeps pointing at the following with an error:

```
numshapes= random.randint(4, 9)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\current\robotics\project\AbstractAutomatica.py", line 361, in <module>

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'randint'
```

In the beginning of the file I imported random:

```
import random
```

Comment: Could you please show the surrounding code?

Comment: Perhaps you overwrote the name `random` somewhere in your code?

Comment: There's about 380 lines of code before the error but they are all functions.

Comment: Try pasting the line `numshapes = random.randint(4, 9)` one line  after the `import random` statement. Does the error get thrown there as well?

Comment: Could you list all your global varibles?

Comment: #twasbrillig Yes it does get thrown if I paste it right after import random

Comment: do you import anything else?

Comment: Yes, Myro. It's software for robots. I am considering trying it without random.

Comment: @munchschair newer calico or old CPython version?

Comment: nevermind, it doesn't matter

Comment: I removed random from randint(). It works. I think maybe myro has its own randomint function and it is clashing with random's randint function.

Comment: I can't find anything on a randint named function in myro. What is your compiler?

Comment: `print(repr(random))` says what?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and its cause was very simple:

```
from pylab import *
```

after importing random. `pylab random` has overwritten the `random` module.